# How do you compute a Djikstra Heat Map with multiple sources?

Tags: algorithm, path

Currently, so far I am using a level-wise BFS which traverses throughout the grid and the values(calulcated by looking at the level) essentially is the distance its from the source. How, do I implement this so I have multiple heat sources? Does this mean I will have to compute multiple level-wise BFS, after iterating one level for the BFS for source 1, I move on to source 2 and etc

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I can do to iteratively for one. And for the next few sources I have to have a couple of conditional statements which prevent me from overwriting too much.